# TinyMCE escapes all tags upon saving

Tags: java, javascript, tinymce-4

this question is somwhat related to [TinyMCE displaying html tags after saving and reloading the data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11706359/tinymce-displaying-html-tags-after-saving-and-reloading-the-data) but since i'm not using encoding: xml, the answers didn't help me much.

This is how i initialize TinyMCE:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            tinymce.init({
                selector: "textarea", 
                language: "de",  
                plugins: ["table, visualblocks"], 
                visualblocks_default_state: false, 
                whitespace_elements: "p, li, table", 
                menubar: false, 
                toolbar: "visualblocks | bold italic underline strikethrough | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | " +
                         "subscript superscript | bullist numlist | table", 
                statusbar: true, 
                resize: true
            });
        });
```

After typing, say an 'a' into the editor and calling Editor.save() all tags are escaped and, upon reloding, are shown inside the editor, like this (not enough reputation to post images...):

```
<p>a</p>
```

The textarea itself contains:

```
&lt;p&gt;a&lt;/p&gt;
```

After saving again, i get more tags etc. Linebreaks are lost as well, as both paragraphs are treaded as simple text again.

The editor is placed inside a jsf portlet, if that has anything to do with it.

Thanks in advance.

Update: If i unescape TinyMCE's output before saving to DB, everything works fine. However, this also allows me to put any markup by hand and displays unescaped html code inside the textarea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the portal server WAS responsible, after all. After porting the project from WebSphere Portal 8.0 to 8.5, everything seems to work.