# How to ignore html tags in tinymce | Vuejs and Laravel

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, tinymce

I am building an application using laravel and vuejs but for some reason I cannot use tinymce properly.

I see the editor as I want and write whatever I want in it. But when I try to view the content, all the html tags show as you can see in the image

[image]

I installed it following the github documentation [here](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce-vue)

```
npm install @tinymce/tinymce-vue
```

Imported in my vue template

```
import Editor from '@tinymce/tinymce-vue';

components: {
    'editor' : Editor
}
```

And then I bind the element

```
<editor v-model="post.description"></editor>
```

So instead of showing " This text will be **bold**", it should show me "This text will be **bold**"

Comment: I don't get what is your intention: do you want the `<p>` tags excluded from every line is that it ?

Comment: Yes. Like the text should be shown as bold and not <strong>bold</strong>

Comment: Are you trying to input HTML tags on the editor instead of using the GUI formatting ?

Comment: Give you an example: when am on tinymce editor I type a paragraph and one of the words I choose to be bold. When I view the actual post with that paragraph, I do not see that word that was meant to be bold, instead I see the actual html tags. like in the image I posted. Cause I do not need the users to see any html tag

Comment: See the source of the page which has the post. Perhaps your backend is escaping tags. Do you get `&lt;p&gt;` in source instead of `<p>` for instance ? It seems tinymce is doing its job right.

Comment: Did you give up on this problem ?

Comment: @Niloct Never ever. I just posted the answer

Answer (score 3):

After some research I ended up realising that I had to use the v-html in order to read the html tags

so instead of showing like this:

```
<td>{{post.description}}<td>
```

I am now doing the following:

```
<td v-html="post.description"><td>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using TinyMCE proper way. It returns HTML, not a plain text. And when you remove tags from that returned HTML, you will lost all formatting, images and links. But if this is what are you looking for, just dive into TinyMCE documentation - it's a question of configuration.